# Updating Old Realm Objects From 2016 Causes Crash

Tags: xcode, realm

Help! I'm updating an old Xcode project from 2016 and I'm encountering crashes when working with my Realm objects.

I have a game I built in Xcode with swift 3 and put in the AppStore in 2016. It used Realm for my Game objects. It was one of my first projects so recently I decided to revisit the project and update the code, clean it up (I was very new to Swift), make it work with newer devices and screens, fix a couple bugs, add a few features, etc. When going through the updates to the current languages, I can no longer save my Game object because in 2016, the Realm properties were written as:

```
    dynamic var numCorrect: Int = 0
    dynamic var numWrong: Int = 0
    dynamic var score: Int = 0
    dynamic var stars: Int = 0
    dynamic var date = NSDate() 
...
```

Now Realm requires "@objc" before "dynamic var". So it's now:

```
    @objc dynamic var numCorrect: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var numWrong: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var score: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var stars: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var date = NSDate()
```

With this change/addition everything works great. UNTIL I try to update on top of the old/current version in the App Store. It crashes when trying to create a new Game object.

I assume there's some way to migrate but I can't figure it out. The migration guide doesn't address upgrading from an old version of Realm to a new version.

Here's the log:

```
/Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-core_release_6.0.6/src/realm/group.hpp:1149: [realm-core-6.0.6] Assertion failed: m_top.size() > s_hist_version_ndx
0   Realm                               0x0000000103b5db04 _ZN5realm4utilL18terminate_internalERNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 28
1   Realm                               0x0000000103b5dda0 _ZN5realm4util9terminateEPKcS2_lOSt16initializer_listINS0_9PrintableEE + 324
2   Realm                               0x0000000103a97720 _ZN5realm2DB19upgrade_file_formatEbiii + 980
3   Realm                               0x0000000103a95130 _ZN5realm2DB7do_openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbbNS_9DBOptionsE + 3092
4   Realm                               0x0000000103a97b20 _ZN5realm2DB4openERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 244
5   Realm                               0x0000000103a9c0a4 _ZN5realm2DB6createERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 392
6   Realm                               0x0000000103644a44 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator7open_dbEv + 972
7   Realm                               0x0000000103643c98 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator12do_get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigERNSt3__110shared_ptrIS2_EENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEERNS8_17CheckedUniqueLockE + 72
8   Realm                               0x0000000103643b30 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEE + 268
9   Realm                               0x0000000103895ae0 _ZN5realm5Realm16get_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigE + 152
10  Realm                               0x00000001037e0434 +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:queue:error:] + 1704
11  RealmSwift                          0x0000000104be1660 $sSo8RLMRealmC13configuration5queueABSo0A13ConfigurationC_So012OS_dispatch_C0CSgtKcfCTO + 156
12  RealmSwift                          0x0000000104c18aa8 $s10RealmSwift0A0V5queueACSo012OS_dispatch_C0CSg_tKcfC + 140
13  Scrath                              0x00000001028afa4c $s6Scrath11AppDelegateC11updateRealmyyF + 680
14  Scrath                              0x00000001028af438 $s6Scrath11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtF + 288
15  Scrath                              0x00000001028af534 $s6Scrath11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtFTo + 232
16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c31e478c 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 10893196
17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c31e656c 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 10900844
18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c31ebf68 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 10923880
19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c295eb50 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1956688
20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2e29510 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
21  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c295f684 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1959556
22  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c295f0b0 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1958064
23  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c295f4a0 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1959072
24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c295ed28 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1957160
25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2963444 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1975364
26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2d48080 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 6058112
27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2e431b4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 260
28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2963180 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1974656
29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2e4309c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 108
30  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2962fd8 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 1974232
31  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c27c8db8 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 294328
32  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c27c78b8 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 288952
33  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c27c8ae8 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 293608
34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c31ea200 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 10916352
35  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c2d6ea50 66C0BDEB-71CF-3148-AF27-A5B055FAD9A5 + 6216272
36  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c4304bec 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 52204
37  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c432b190 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 209296
38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c430faac 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 96940
39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c432ae24 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 208420
40  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104da318c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104da6964 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 368
42  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c43512b4 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 365236
43  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c4350f60 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 364384
44  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001c43514cc 039FCB83-A7EC-3872-94E8-DD490434EAEB + 365772
45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bf01f860 9624AAFD-5437-3772-A507-0F357875808D + 710752
46  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bf01f7b4 9624AAFD-5437-3772-A507-0F357875808D + 710580
47  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bf01ef04 9624AAFD-5437-3772-A507-0F357875808D + 708356
48  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bf019ca4 9624AAFD-5437-3772-A507-0F357875808D + 687268
49  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bf019660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
50  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001c942a604 GSEventRunModal + 164
51  UIKitCore                           0x00000001c31ee15c UIApplicationMain + 1944
52  Scrath                              0x00000001028b16a4 main + 80
53  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001bee951ec 95B366E7-F5BD-3308-9416-24B35999029B + 4588!!! IMPORTANT: Please send this log and info about Realm SDK version and other relevant reproduction info to help@realm.io
```

Please, does anyone know how to solve this? It's not like this app is popular but I don't want to require any previous user to delete the app in order to use the new version.

Comment: The issue you're describing is a bit unclear and it seems there are multiple questions. It states that after updating to use @objc, the app works great, but then you're saying it crashes? What does 'updating from the old version' mean specifically? It also mentions 'some way to migrate'... are you asking about migrating your data to new version which is covered in the Realm getting started guide [Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) or something else? Can you update and clarify (the question) with clearer information and also clarify 'crashes when creating a new object'

Comment: @Jay, I've updated my post. I hope it clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Well, not really lol. It sounds like you're asking how to Migrate your old realm data to a newer file, which is covered in the Migrations section of the documentation I linked above. Is that what you're asking? Can you provide the code that's crashing and indicate what line is causing the error? Using a breakpoint to step through your code would be helpful.

Comment: @Jay, that's exactly what I'm asking. Except I have tried all three types of migrations suggested by Realm. I tried the minimal migration with "//Nothing to do!". I tried Updating Values, very similar (and then exactly) as suggested by rs7 below. I tried Renaming Properties, first "from 'numCorrect' to 'numCorrect'" and then I changed the names of the properties, adding "New" to the end of each and trying to rename (so "from 'numCorrect' to 'numCorrectNew'"). Every time I get the same crash.

Comment: Well, here's where we are; there's a crash but you've not stepped through your code to know what line is crashing. There's a migration but we can't see the code so we don't know what line is crashing. You can help us to help you by including the necessary items so we can try to answer. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then update your question with code, your troubleshooting steps and we'll take a look!

Comment: @MeaganS. Have you tried using a slightly older version of Realm? I believe that version 5 is the latest. I recently upgraded to Realm 5.0 which resulted in a similar stack trace. It's not exact, but there are several matches in the call stack. I personally believe this to be a Realm bug. I know it's not a fix, but at least for now, on your development device, I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling to see if it solves the problem. Also, you will notice that your log suggests filing a bug at help@realm.io. I have done that, but they told me to file an issue on github.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree Thank You! That was it! I just downgraded to v 4.4.1 and everything works perfectly!

Comment: The problem you're going to run into as that as soon as you use Realm Studio to view your data, it's going to make your code not work again because it will upgrade your Realm file which is not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem, it appears to be a bug with Realm's current version. In my podfile I wrote:

```
    pod 'RealmSwift', '<5.0'
    pod 'Realm', '<5.0'
```

And now my project runs perfectly. Thanks @RobertCrabtree!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement a migration block and use enumerate as follows:

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Object.className()) { (oldObject, newObject) in
    guard let numCorrect = oldObject?["numCorrect"] as? Int else {
        fatalError("numCorrect is not a Int")
    }
    // List all the rest of your properties the same way (i.e., with a guard statement)

    // Then assign old object value to new property
    newObject?["numCorrect"] = numCorrect

}
```

Make sure you implement your migration block properly with the right version etc..